# android BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE always in release status

Tags: android, buildconfig, android-flavors

I am implementing a new functionality that depending on whether the application is running, debug or release, choose between two url.

This is the code that I use insidel gradle to choose which url use ->

[image: Code in side gradle]

In the line below, is where I want to get the correct url, but when I'm debbuging   with build variants in debug, the code returns me release url.

Line of code to get url ->
[image: Code get url]

Url that I get ->
 [image: URL Image]

Check BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE ->

[image: BuildConfig]

I'm getting release mode, why? 
Doing some research in BUILD_TYPE I found diferents BuildConfig which two of them  have the BUILD_TYPE in release ->

[image: Release Mode]

And the only diference between them was this -> 
The ones that has BUILD_TYPE = "debug" have DEBUG like this ->

[image: Build Type]

The BUILD_TYPE = "release" have DEBUG like this ->

[image: DEBUG Image]

How can I change the ones that are in release to debug? Knowing that BuildConfig class is generated alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
android {
...
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->

        if (variant.getName() == "release") {
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEND_EMAIL", "\"https://www.google.com\""
        } else {
            variant.buildConfigField "String", "URL_SEND_EMAIL", "\"https://www.gmail.com\""
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to select your build variant in the window normally found at the bottom-left of android studio: [image]

Comment: All my build variants are in Debug type as I said before

Comment: Try to clean your gradle build